# Difference between location.pathname and match.url in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

What's the difference between `props.location.pathname` and `props.match.url`

in `react-router-dom`?

From their DOCS: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

> **match.url**
>
> (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s
>
> **location**
>
> A location object to be used for matching children elements instead of the current history location (usually the current browser URL).

So far, I've ony seen them with exact same values.

**Example:**

If my route is matched in this url:

`/search/searchValue?category=whatever`

And I want to remove the query strings and go to:

`/search/searchValue`

Should I use one over the other or they both will work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`location.pathname` represents the **root-relative url**.

`match.url` represents the **matched portion of the URL**, so maybe a portion of `location.pathname`.

Given these two components :

```
function Home({match, location}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {match.url}
      <br/>
      {location.pathname}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you go to `/something`, then

- **match.url** will be **/** (because the matched portion of the URL is `/`)
- **location.pathname** will be **/something** (the relative-root URL)

Here is the [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-match-location).

In your example, it depends whether your route is matching the exact path or not (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool).

If it's not the case (and you only want to retrieve `/search/searchValue`) then you should use `match.url` because `location.pathname` could be more than `/search/searchValue` -> `/search/searchValue/something`.